# Do we need the tutorials tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a few pending edits in the queue right that that remove [tutorials](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials).

It appears that if all of these edits are approved, that [tutorials](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials) will not be on any questions anymore, so it will be deleted the night after.

I think the general consensus is that questions inquiring about tutorials aren't a good fit here, but those questions are still open, so that tags makes sense.

What are others thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions about tutorials have the same problem questions about resource links have:

- They are not constructive, as they don't require a specific expertise to be answered.
- They are rather subjective, as everybody could provide a different list of resource links.
- Their answers don't provide an explanation of why a specific tutorial is suggested, such as why that specific tutorial is preferable to another one.
- Looking at different questions about tutorials, you will notice that some of the links point to the same web site.
- Their answers don't provide a solution to a problem, but they give a link to a page where a specific problem is resolved.

The more important problem with those questions is evident in this answer:

> You could try NodeOne videos [here](http://nodeone.se/drupal-module/organic-groups).

[image: 404: page not found]

Rather than asking for a tutorial about doing *X*, it would be better if the question would be specific on how doing *X*.

The tag should be removed from the questions, which should be closed as not constructive.